# Mentioning directory together with glob

Tags: php

I have this script to access all the xml files in a folder.
But how would I specify a directory inside the glob ?

Here's my code :-

```
foreach (glob("*.xml*") as $filename) {
    echo $filename."<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the directory in this way :-

```
$dir="dirname/";
foreach (glob("$dir*.xml*") as $filename) {
    echo $filename."<br />";
}
```

**Notice** :- When you echo the filename, the directory would come attached to it. So for instance the filename is example.txt, then the output will be dirname/output.txt. You can then use explode to remoe the dir name.